# draw satellite covarage zone on equirectangular projection

Tags: c++, distortion, satellite

I need to draw borders of the observation zone of satellite on equirectangular projection. I found this formulas (1) and figure:

```
sin(fi) = cos(alpha) * sin(fiSat) – sin(alpha) * sin (Beta) * cos (fiSat);

sin(lambda) = (cos(alpha) * cos(fiSat) * sin(lambdaSat)) / cos(asin(sin(fi))) +
              (sin(alpha) * sin(Beta) * sin(fiSat) * sin(lambdaSat)) / cos(asin(sin(fi))) -
              (sin(alpha) * cos(Beta) * cos(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sin(fi)));

cos(lambda) = (cos(alpha) * cos(fiSat) * cos(lambdaSat)) / cos(asin(sin(fi))) +
              (sin(alpha) * sin(Beta) * sin(fiSat) * cos(lambdaSat)) / cos(asin(sin(fi))) -
              (sin(alpha) * cos(Beta) * sin(lambdaSat)) / cos(asin(sin(fi)));
```

Cross-sections of the Earth in various planes:
[image: Cross-sections of the Earth in various planes]

And equations system (2) with figure:

```
if sin(lambda) > 0, cos(lambda) > 0 then lambda = asin(sin(lambda));
if sin(lambda) > 0, cos(lambda) < 0 then lambda = 180 - asin(sin(lambda));
if sin(lambda) < 0, cos(lambda) < 0 then lambda = 180 - asin(sin(lambda));
if sin(lambda) < 0, cos(lambda) > 0 then lambda = asin(sin(lambda));
```

Scheme of reference angles for the longitude of the Earth:
[image: Scheme of reference angles for the longitude of the Earth]

```
Where:  alpha – polar angle;
    fiSat, lambdaSat – latitude, longitude of satellite;
    Beta – angle which change from 0 to 2*Pi and help to draw the observation zone;
    fi, lambda – latitude, longitude of point B on the border of observation zone;
```

I repeat both (1) and (2) formulas in cycle from 0 to 2*Pi to draw border of observation zone. But I am not quite sure in (2) system of equations.

Inside intervals [-180;-90], [-90;90], [90;180] the zone draws correctly.

Center at -35;45:
[image: Center at -35;45]

Center at 120;60:
[image: Center at 120;60]

Center at -120;-25
[image: Center at -120;-25]

But on border of -90 and 90 degree it get messy:

Center at -95;-50
[image: Center at -95;-50]

Center at 95;30
[image: Center at 95;30]

Can you help me with formulas(1) and (2) or write another ones?

```
double deltaB = 1.0*M_PI/180;
observerZone.clear();
for (double Beta = 0.0; Beta <= (M_PI * 2) ; Beta += deltaB){
    double sinFi = cos(alpha) * sin(fiSat) - sin(alpha) * sin(Beta) * cos(fiSat);
    double sinLambda = (cos(alpha) * cos(fiSat) * sin(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi)) +
                             (sin(alpha) * sin(Beta) * sin(fiSat) * sin(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi)) -
                            (sin(alpha) * cos(Beta) * cos(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi));
    double cosLambda = (cos(alpha) * cos(fiSat) * cos(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi)) +
                            (sin(alpha) * sin(Beta) * sin(fiSat) * cos(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi)) -
                            (sin(alpha) * cos(Beta) * sin(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi));
    if (sinLambda > 0) {
        if (cosLambda > 0 ){
            sinLambda = asin(sinLambda);
            sinFi = asin(sinFi);
        }
        else {
            sinLambda = M_PI - asin(sinLambda);
            sinFi = asin(sinFi);
        }
    }
    else if (cosLambda > 0) {
        sinLambda = asin(sinLambda);
        sinFi = asin(sinFi);
    }
    else {
        sinLambda = -M_PI - asin(sinLambda);
        sinFi = asin(sinFi);
    }
    Point point;
    point.latitude = qRadiansToDegrees(sinFi);
    point.longitude = qRadiansToDegrees(sinLambda);
    observerZone.push_back(point);
}
```

Comment: You state in the 3rd line of formula (2) `if sin(lambda) < 0, cos(lambda) < 0 then lambda = 180 - asin(sin(lambda));`, but your code is `sinLambda = -M_PI - asin(sinLambda);`. That makes it `-180 - asin(sin(lambda))`. Could that cause the problem?

Comment: No, its not, in code i make this to correct the (2) formula. Without this -M_PI - asin(sinLambda); it will draw part of zone on other side of projection. In left side you got only negative longitude (lambda) and if it would be Pi - (-sinLambda) you get positive longitude.

Comment: Can you add the code for `qRadiansToDegrees`?

Comment: qRadiansToDegrees is a QT function which convert radians to degrees. https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmath.h.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. In (1) equation when calculating cosLambda should be + instead of -.

```
double cosLambda = (cos(alpha) * cos(fiSat) * cos(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi)) +
                            (sin(alpha) * sin(Beta) * sin(fiSat) * cos(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi)) +
                            (sin(alpha) * cos(Beta) * sin(lambdaSat))/cos(asin(sinFi));
```

Sorry for disturbing.